R get the indexes of corresponding row in a dataframe
I have two dataframe : df1 and df2. df2 is composed of rows from df1. For each row of df2, I want its index in df1.
For example :
df1 <- data.frame(animal=c('koala', 'hedgehog', 'sloth', 'panda'),
                  country=c('Australia', 'Italy', 'Peru', 'China'),
                  avg_sleep_hours=c(21, 18, 17, 10))
df2 <- data.frame(animal=c('koala', 'sloth', 'panda', 'panda'),
                  country=c('Australia', 'Peru', 'China', 'China'), 
                  avg_sleep_hours=c(21,17,10,10))

I want to get
1 3 4 4

I searched on Internet but found no satisfactory answer, so I wrote my own code.
I know that findIdxRow could return several numbers if a row of df2 is duplicates in df1 but it won't appear in my data, so I didn't take the time to deal with that.
findIdxRow <- function(row, df)
{
  n <- nrow(df)
  is_equal <- sapply(1:n, function(i) all(row==df[i,]))
  return(which(is_equal))
}

indexes <- sapply(1:nrow(df2), function(i) findIdxRow(df2[i,],df1))

This code works, but I wonder if there is a shorter way to write it.

See also R matching more than 2 conditions and return the response value

You can use match on top of paste like below
match(do.call(paste, df2), do.call(paste, df1))

Benchmark
set.seed(42)
n <- 5E3
library(dplyr)
df1 <- data.frame(
  animal = ids::adjective_animal(n),
  country = ids::proquint(n, n_words = 1))

df2 <- df1 |>
  slice_sample(n = n)

f1 <- \() {
  a <- merge(
    df2 |> transform(index_orig = 1:nrow(df2)),
    df1 |> transform(index = 1:nrow(df1))
  )
  a[order(a$index_orig), ]$index
}

f2 <- \() {
  df2 |>
    left_join(df1 |> mutate(index = row_number()), by = join_by(animal, country)) |>
    pull(index)
}


f3 <- \() {
  match(do.call(paste, df2), do.call(paste, df1))
}

microbenchmark(
  f1(),
  f2(),
  f3(),
  unit = "relative",
  check = "equal"
)

which shows
Unit: relative
 expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
 f1() 21.351795 16.785351 15.511564 15.514184 14.906641 9.398281   100
 f2()  3.882332  3.063971  2.929195  2.893312  2.848455 2.389725   100
 f3()  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000 1.000000   100


A join, which is a highly optimized way to relate two data frames, will be far more performant than your original approach or the match approach if your data is more than trivial (~500 rows) size. In my testing, the match approach worked acceptably for slightly larger data, but got much slower than merge/left_join approaches for n > 1000. The join approaches continue to work pretty well even if your data is millions of rows. If you need fast performance on larger data than that, duckdb, data.table, collapse, and arrow, to name a few, may provide further improvements.
In base R:
# (is there a better way to keep the `df2` order?)
a <- merge(df2 |> transform(index_orig = 1:nrow(df2)),
           df1 |> transform(index = 1:nrow(df1)))
a[order(a$index_orig),]$index

Or with dplyr:
library(dplyr)
df2 |>
  left_join(df1 |> mutate(index = row_number())) |>
  pull(index)

Joining with `by = join_by(animal, country, avg_sleep_hours)`
[1] 1 3 4 4


# fake data
set.seed(42)
n <- 1E3  
library(dplyr)
df1 <- data.frame(
  animal = ids::adjective_animal(n),
  country = ids::proquint(n, n_words = 1))
df2 <- df1 |>
  slice_sample(n = n)



tictoc::tic()
df2 |>
  left_join(df1 |> mutate(index = row_number())) |>
  pull(index)
tictoc::toc()
   
tictoc::tic()
a <- merge(df2 |> transform(index_orig = 1:nrow(df2)),
           df1 |> transform(index = 1:nrow(df1)))
a[order(a$index_orig),]$index
tictoc::toc()

tictoc::tic()
match(interaction(df2), 
      interaction(df1))
tictoc::toc()    

tictoc::tic()
findIdxRow <- function(row, df)
{
  n <- nrow(df)
  is_equal <- sapply(1:n, function(i) all(row==df[i,]))
  return(which(is_equal))
}
indexes <- sapply(1:nrow(df2), function(i) findIdxRow(df2[i,],df1))
tictoc::toc()


interesting benchmarking, +1! I think we can use match over strings, which should be faster than join.

In base R, you can use match and interaction:
match(interaction(df2), 
      interaction(df1))

# [1] 1 3 4 4

Though note this approach is probably best used with small data and likely will be inefficient with larger data frames.
